# How to properly package and consume .NET Standard library with multiple runtimes on net472?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.7.2

I am trying to make a multiplatform package for Python.NET, targeting .NET Standard 2.0, using [this project](https://github.com/onovotny/MSBuildSdkExtras/#creating-per-runtimeidentifier-packages).

I managed to create a NuGet package with the following structure:

```
ref
|- netstandard2.0
 |- Python.Runtime.dll
runtimes
|- win
 |- lib
  |- netstandard2.0
   |- Python.Runtime.dll
|- linux-x64
 |- ...
```

This package works perfectly with a test app, based on the new .csproj format + `PackageReferece`, but only if I target `netcoreappX.X`. In that case it copies the whole `runtimes` folder to the output on `dotnet publish` and runs without a problem.

If I change `TargetFramework` to `net472`, both `dotnet build` and `dotnet publish` on Windows fail to copy any version of Python.Runtime.dll from the package, causing `FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Python.Runtime, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

The same exception is raised when trying to run from Visual Studio.

The exception actually makes sense, as I can see the assembly is not copied to the output directory.

Now the question is which of the following is the problem, and how do I fix it:

1. my .nuget package lacking something, so nothing is picked up for `net472` target (though I'd expect it simply using `netstandard2.0` stuff)
2. my test app .csproj is missing something (maybe I need to specify in the .csproj all the supported runtimes?)
3. a setup like this is not supported by tooling at all

If there is a solution to the above problem, would it also work for the old-style .NET Framework projects with `packages.config`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Oren Novotny in https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/10806, there are two important things.

When using `dotnet run` or `dotnet publish` with `net4xx` targets, in this case `--runtime` has to be specified.

For `dotnet publish` a generic one seems to be fine: `dotnet run -r win`.

For `dotnet run` I had to specify a concrete one: `dotnet run -r win7-x64`.

To avoid that, I'd have to add lib/net4XX/ to the package in addition to its current content (not tried yet).